# Calculate Average Error Rate in KNN

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I have been given different error rates for k=1,2,3.

How to calculate the average value of error,and determine whether it is a good error rate or not?

Comment: To answer you better, it would be great if you can provide us some sample data along with a bit explanation of the data/features. give us your error rate  too. Because the error rate is very crucial and varies differently with respect to different business problem.

Comment: Consider the following results from a five-fold cross validation
Fold Error%
K=1    19.25
K=2   19.76
K=3   18.99
K=4   19.88
K=5   14.21

Comment: all these are train error or test errors?

Comment: errors from 5 fold cross validation..!

Comment: not specified whether test or train!

Comment: It would be train error, as we use cross fold technique for training the model with out any repetition.

Comment: should i calculate the weighted or simple average?

Comment: why do you want calculate average error rate? see you decide some K value i.e., which every gives minimal error(but shouldn't be very high K values for very little data), you need to check test error too before deciding the value for K.

Comment: the question asks to find the average error e!

Comment: Do yo know why we use KNN? the reason why I'm asking is based on your problem I can suggest you , we just use error for each K value to decide K and we can use that value of K at the time of implementation of model for classification. But you are asking for average. Which doesn't make any sense(to me).  If you take average of those error it wouldn't take you any where.

Comment: You are talking with respect to k-fold cross validation or KNN?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the explanation you gave I think you are talking about **k-fold Cross validation**.

Assuming it as k-fold cross validation then you need to take mean of all the error rates. And the mean outcome would be your final error rate.